# How to create obfuscated package in Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2?

Tags: java-me, proguard, java-wireless-toolkit

I would like to create obfuscated package of my j2me application for improving the size and performance.So, I have downloaded `proguard` from sourgeforge.net. I have put the `proguard.jar` into my `C:\WTK2.5.2_01\bin` folder.

When I try to create obfuscated package from `project->package->Create Obfuscation package` it raised the following exception

```
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  Error: C:\Documents (The system cannot find the file specified)
  Obfuscation failed.
  Build failed
```

So, What is the cause of this error message and How do I obfuscate my application?

Comment: Check [this link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/wtk.html), see if it helps.

Comment: where are your IDE and project located? somewhere in `C:\Documents and Settings` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure you are using ProGuard's own WTK plugin, not the one from Oracle/Sun (which has a problem with spaces in path names). Cfr. [ProGuard manual > JME WTK](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/wtk.html).

Answer (score 1):

In j2me obfuscation requires Obfuscation tool.Progaurd is one of the good obfuscation tool.

U should install proguard in ur system.Then u goto Wirless toolkit ,select preferences,then the obfuscation setting, specifying the obfuscation tool path (Where ur progaurd in installed in ur system-proguard path).

Then after creating a project,after creating source file.For creating jar/jad u should select create package 4m wtk(wirless tool kit),instead of selecting create package,select "Create obfuscating /create obfuscation package" .Then the jad/jar is created with obfuscation files.

The obfuscation is same as normal java